# Change octave of built in chords in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

Lilypond has some built in chords which can be conveniently used with \chordmode

```
\new StaffGroup <<                                                                  
  \new Staff \with {                                                                
    instrumentName = "Piano"                                                        
    shortInstrumentName = "Pno"                                                     
  } \new Voice = "voice" \relative c {                                             
    \key b \major                                                                   
    \easyHeadsOn                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                    
    \chordmode {                                                                    
      b1                                                                            
    }                                                                               
  }                                                                                 
>>
```

This produces:

[image]

Chordnames can also be printed with \chords:

```
\new StaffGroup <<
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Piano"
    shortInstrumentName = "Pno"
  } \new Voice = "voice" \relative c {
    \key b \major
    \easyHeadsOn

    \chords {
      \chordmode {
        b1
      }
    }
  }
>>
```

This produces:

[image]

Is there a way to customize these built in chords ? Some of them do not sound good in the midi. I would prefer to use lower octave, for example. Just changing to relative c, does not seem to work.

I am aware I can write my own chords using <> notation, but I just want to print
chord names in the final output and have an acceptable midi. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do `b,1`. `\chordmode` is a special parser mode that does not use relative information, so you need to specify the octave for each note.

Comment: Hmm.. why didn't I think of that :-(

Comment: In general is it possible to customize these chords (without writing my own) ? May be I want 4 notes instead of 3 ?

Comment: It is not possible directly in the parser. You may add additional notes like this `b:3.5.8` or by either wrapping the chords around a music function which post processes the chords. Consider this answer https://music.stackexchange.com/a/122051/82808 where is implemented a function that replaces chords by the voicings from fretboad diagram definitions.

Comment: If the chords are consistently in the wrong octave one of these functions might be helpful: [`\transposition`](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/notation/instrument-transpositions), [`\transpose`](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/changing-multiple-pitches#transpose)